# Подскажите как в AJAX запросе получить файл

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Расположение файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл `auto.json`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь в реакте подключится получить данный файл, и в дальнейшем работать с данными. В консоли браузера пишет `Null`, подскажите где ошибка в запросе?

```js
import React from "react";
import PageOne from "./pageone";


class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state = {
     WeatherObj:null
   }
  }
 componentWillMount(){
  this.getWeather();
 }
 getWeather(){
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onload = () => {
   this.setState({WeatherObj:req.response});
  }
  req.open("GET", "auto.json", true);
  req.responseType = "json";
  req.send();
 }


 render() {  
  let weather = this.state.WeatherObj;
  console.log(weather);
       return(
        <button>Запустить</button>
       )
    
 

 }

}
export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Перед тем как отправить файл, его нужно прочитать. Используйте FileReader https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Куда отправить? Я пытаюсь его получить

Comment: и что Вы с ним потом делать планируете?

Comment: Потом я собираюсь работать с его данными

Comment: Я пытаюсь считать json данные из файла

Comment: a `Ajax` Вам зачем?

Comment: Преподаватель на курсах сказал, заменить на файл, и считает файл

Comment: Я, конечно, могу чего-то не знать, но у меня есть стойкое мнение, что `AJAX` предназначен только лишь для отправки запроса на сервер и получения ответа на этот запрос. Для чтения файлов есть `FileReader`.

Comment: строка `auto.json`  говорит СЕРВЕРУ, что Вам необходим этот файл. Сервер обработает эту инфу и пришлет Вам его, если, конечно, он будет обучен этому.